# How to write a subquery in Hive

Tags: subquery, hive

I am stuck on a query. 
I have data like

```
  Uid, resp-date,camp-type

   1       201403    A
   1       201406    A
   1       201406    B
   1       201406    B
   1       201407    A
   1       201407    B
   2       201402    A
   2       201406    A
   2       201406    B
```

And  want to create some metrics like #of prod offered in last month, 
The counting logic is:
If the product is A count the number of products offered in the last n month
If the product is B then count the number of products offered in last n months + number of product type A offered in the current month

```
  Uid, resp-date,prod-type,#offered-last1month, #offered-last2month
    1       201403    A                0                  0
    1       201406    A                0                  0
    1       201406    B                1                  1
    1       201406    B                1                  1
    1       201407    A                3                  3
    1       201407    B                4                  4
     2       201402    A               0                  0
     2       201406    A               0                  0                     
     2       201406    B               1                  1
```

query:

```
Select m.uid, m.respdate,m.prodtype, 
           case when m.prodtype ='A' then ca.num-mails-1month
                     when m.prodtype ='B' then cb.num-mails-1month
           end as mails-last1month
from m

 Left outer Join 
  ( select uid, count(* ) as num-mails-1month from 
      (
       What is a way around to write a sub query that refers m.resp-date
      ) 
  ) ca
 on ca.uid =m.uid

  Left outer Join 
     ( select uid, count(* ) as num-mails-1month from 
        (

         )

       ) cb
       on cb.uid =m.uid
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Or what have you tried?

Comment: How can I implement this logic in the query?